# User is not authorized to perform: dynamodb:GetItem

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-iam, vercel

I've created my api in vercel, which uses aws lambda. In my function, I've used a call to dynamodb in my aws account.

But I keep getting `AccessDeniedException`.
But, When I run it locally, there is no issue.

```
AccessDeniedException: User: arn:aws:sts::764717618004:assumed-role/cloudwatch_logs_events_putter/L0ZFqQmkoVXQ44u8QwB1yH0f-805fd9d54732e5470e54bf12bd9a25672e379b5 
is not authorized to perform: dynamodb:GetItem on resource: arn:aws:dynamodb:ap-south-1:764717618004:table/users
```

[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42602798/lambda-and-dynamodb-is-not-authorized-to-perform-dynamodbscan) adresses the issue when both lambda and dynamo are of the same user account.

Comment: Have you given the `cloudwatch_logs_events_putter` role permissions for `dynamodb:GetItem`?

Comment: I can't find any role with that name. I'm new to this. Should I be creating a role in that name? I've already given `AmazonDynamoDBFullAccess` to the IAM user.

Comment: You’ll have to update the policy for the `Role`, not the `User`.

Comment: There was no such role to begin with, so I created one and gave permissions, but it's still not working.

Comment: The role existed because your Lambda had assumed it and STS had issued credentials which are not authorized. If you don’t see the role, is it possible it’s in a different account, or that you don’t have permissions to see it?

Comment: The lambda is in another account (vercel.com) and I don't have permission to do anything. How would I let that lambda use my dynamodb? Creating role hasn't helped much. Or maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: Sorry, am not familiar with vercel.com; maybe reach out to them for support with cross account permissions.

Comment: They don't have any option to change anything. I've looked through the whole documentation and couldn't find anything. I've also started a discussion in github/vercel, but did not get any reply till now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well guess what, after hours of combing through aws documentation I got to the root of the issue.
The user: `arn:aws:sts::764717618004:assumed-role/` and `arn:aws:dynamodb:ap-south-1:764717618004:table/users` are the same, which was odd once I thought about it.

Because the aws Id of dynamodb should've been mine, but it's evidently not. So I tried logging the `accessKeyId`, and to my surprise it was not what I set in the Environment.
Then I just checked out what's in `vercel env ls`. There was nothing wrong at first sight, but then I noticed a little typo in the `DYNAMODB_ACCESS_KYE_ID`.

**YES IT WAS JUST A TYPO**. successfully wasted 6+ hours on a typo in environment variable.